# Woocommerce Wishlist Add to Cart also Adds to Wishlist

Tags: ajax, woocommerce

I am trying to build a WooCommerce site and added WooCommerce wishlist plugin free version and it works as it should. No problems.

What I would like to achieve is when a customer adds a product to cart, it also adds that product to wishlist if it is not already there.

Is it possible to achieve the above by using hooks?

Here is what I have added in my functions file:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'trigger_for_ajax_add_to_cart' );
function trigger_for_ajax_add_to_cart() { 
    ?> <script type="text/javascript"> 
           (function($){ 
               $('body').on( 'added_to_cart', function(){ 
               // code goes in here 
               }); 
           })(jQuery); 
        </script> 
<?php } ?>
```

Also trying several javascript code from the wishlist plugin files but to no avail.

Comment: Everything is possible. What have you tried so far? Can you show your efforts?

Comment: I have tried the following code in my functions file: add_action( 'wp_footer', 'trigger_for_ajax_add_to_cart' );
function trigger_for_ajax_add_to_cart() {
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($){
                $('body').on( 'added_to_cart', function(){
// code goes in here
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
    <?php
}  trying out several javascript code from the ti wishlist plugin files but to no avail

Comment: Added code snipped from commnt to the question itself.